# Setting the theme of the application during execution just doesn't affect a page

Tags: c#, uwp

I have the following code to changing my theme (the same used by [Xaml-Controls-Gallery](https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery/blob/master/XamlControlsGallery/Helper/ThemeHelper.cs#L54-L60)):

```cs
if (Window.Current.Content is FrameworkElement rootElement)
{
    rootElement.RequestedTheme = value;
}
```

But changing the theme like this or directly in the page's constructor (`this.RequestedTheme = desiredTheme;`) just doesn't affect the theme of that specific page, that page follows the `App.Current.RequestedTheme` (which can only be changed when opening the app).

[image: XiQjUSjtXD]

Comment: After testing, “rootElement.RequestedTheme = value” works well. When I use “Frame.Navigate()” to navigate to other pages, the theme still changes. I can’t reproduce your issue.
Could you please provide us a [mcve] by OneDrive or GitHub for testing?

Comment: I pushed the changes to my personal repository (even with the problem), unfortunately I don't have time to provide a minimum example atm, I so sorry. You may take a look at my repository here: https://github.com/srjheam/Wallddit
Thanks for helping!

Comment: A minimal sample is good for troubleshooting, if you do not post any code that could reproduce this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st: Make sure to have the background bellow among your XAML namespaces declarations:

```
<Page
    ...
    Background={ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}>
```

2nd: Change all theme sensitive resources from `{StaticResource Foo}` to `{ThemeResource Foo}`

I know, this is probably a newbie problem, but I was stuck in it for two nights, so I hope to help someone who will face it in the future.